# What does "-0x1(%edx,%ecx,1)" mean in objdump output?

Tags: assembly, objdump

Using objdump to understand a binary and I realize I'm not fluent enough in ASM syntax. What does the following notion mean?

```
xor    %al,-0x1(%edx,%ecx,1)
```

And while you're at it - what should I search for in order to find docs about such notions?

Comment: Note, I _do_ know what the xor means ;), I just don't understand the parentheses expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parentheses are memory offsets:

`-0x1(%edx,%ecx,1)` (AT&T syntax) is equal to `[edx+ecx*1-1]` (Intel syntax)

Quick guide for [AT&T assembly syntax](http://sig9.com/articles/att-syntax) (as per your request).

Comment: Here is a side-by-side view of [**Intel and AT&T Syntax**](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm).

Answer (score 3):

This is an exclusive or with content of the low byte (%al) of the 'a' register and the content of the memory at the address which is the sum of the 32 bit wide registers 'd' (%edx), 'c' multiplied by 1 (%ecx,1) and -1. The result is written back to %al. In C

```
al ^= (char*)(edx+ecx*1 - 1);
```

You can lookup stuff like this at [sandpile](http://www.sandpile.org/) or in the intel/amd documentation.